# AS3: determine positions of inserted instances of movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

if i insert multiple instances of movie clip with addChild method and "for" loop, how can i determine exact x, y position of instances in the scene? Either specific x y for each instance or placing the instances next to each other with specified space between them. Let's say 40px width squares with 20px space between them.
many thanks for any advices

Comment: So far i have only this: `for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
var testSquare:square = new square();
addChild(testSquare);
}` It's not for any real project, it's just for study purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example show the squares in a row with 20px space between them:

```
        var xSquare:Number = 10;
        var ySquare:Number = 10;
        var space:Number = 20; 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            var testSquare:Square = new Square(); 
            addChild(testSquare);
            testSquare.x = xSquare + testSquare.width * i + space * i ; 
            testSquare.y = ySquare; 
        }
```

Hope this is what you mean

Comment: thanks, this is what i want :) just want to be sure i get it write: in this part of the code `testSquare.x = xSquare + testSquare.width * i + space * i ;` value of `i` for the first instance of testSqaure is 1 or 0?

Comment: Ur welcome.The variable i is 0 for the first instance of testSqaure.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting your objects to stage, give all of them a name (obj0, obj1, obj2, etc). Next, you can simply use getChildByName('objX'). Is this what you need?

Comment: since i'm new in actionscript, so far i haven't came across getChildByName, so it could be what ineed :) could you explain me please, how can to use it? I also don't know how to add number to the name of movie clip's instance. I found this `for (var i:Number=0; i<10 , i++) {var my_mc = new MovieClip(); my_mc.name = "mc"+i; addChild(my_mc);} ` but it didn't work when I tried. many thanks

Comment: @ondrags in your loop you forgot to add variable type. So it should look like this:
`for (var i:Number=0; i<10 , i++) {var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); my_mc.name = "mc"+i; addChild(my_mc);}`
then it will work. Next you can call all the MCs by another loop:
`for (var i:Number=0; i<10 , i++) {var my_mc:MovieClip = getChildByName("mc"+i) as MovieClip; }`

Comment: and how can i determine x y position of the "mc" instances? thanks